# How to properly setup mock data for unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

Having some issues setting up my mock data for a unit test in my API. The data is retrieved from a service.
Here is my endpoint and how the data is retrieved:

```
RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesResponse response
                    = await ResolveServiceClient().RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesAsync(new RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesRequest());

                List<ExceptionReportSessionDataModel> result
                    = GetSessionData(response.RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesResult);

                if (result != null && result.Count > 0)
                {
                    logText = LogFormatter.Format(
                                    WebUtilities.GetUser((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity),
                                    startTime, DateTime.Now, Privilege.EditSession,
                                    "Get Exception Report Session Data", "Exception Report Session Data retrieved successfully.");
                    logger.LogInfo(logText);
                }
                else
                {
                    logText = LogFormatter.Format(
                                    WebUtilities.GetUser((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity),
                                    startTime, DateTime.Now, Privilege.ViewOrderExceptionReport,
                                    "Get exception report session data", "Exception report session data is null or empty.");
                    logger.LogWarn(logText);
                }
                return Ok(result);
```

Here is what I have so far in setting up my unit test:

```
//Arrange          
            List<ExceptionReportSessionDataModel> sessionData = new List<ExceptionReportSessionDataModel>()
            { 
                new ExceptionReportSessionDataModel() {SessionName = "Session1", ReportFiles = null },
                new ExceptionReportSessionDataModel() {SessionName = "Session2", ReportFiles = null },
                new ExceptionReportSessionDataModel() {SessionName = "Session3", ReportFiles = null }
            };

            //NEED HELP HERE
            var ERSessionDataMock = new Mock<>();
            ERSessionDataMock.Setup(x => x.).Returns();

            var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger>();
            loggerMock.Setup(x => x.LogInfo(null));
```

GetSessionData Method:

```
public List<ExceptionReportSessionDataModel> GetSessionData(string sessionData)
        {
            List<ExceptionReportSessionDataModel> reports = new List<ExceptionReportSessionDataModel>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionData))
            {
                string[] splitString = sessionData.Split("\n", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                foreach (string s in splitString)
                {
                    string[] temp = s.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    List<string> files = new List<string>();

                    for (int index = 1; index < temp.Length; index++)
                    {
                        files.Add(temp[index]);
                    }
                    reports.Add(new ExceptionReportSessionDataModel()
                    {
                        ReportFiles = files,
                        SessionName = temp[0]
                    });
                }
            }
            return reports;
        }
```

I need help setting up the ERSessionDataMock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to know without seeing how the `GetSessionData` method is implemented. But here are some quick suggestions:

1. Inject your `ServiceClient` as a dependency instead of calling a method to get it. It needs to either:

   - be an `interface` (like `IServiceClient`) - then in your `Startup.cs` class:

     ```cs
     services.AddScoped<IServiceClient>(sp => ResolveServiceClient().Result);
     ```
   - or the `RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesAsync` method needs to be `virtual` or `abstract` so you can override it with a mock:

     ```cs
     public virtual RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesAsync(RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesRequest request);
     ```
2. Then in your test, create a `response` variable that will exercise the `GetSessionData` in a certain way to get either an empty `List<ExceptionReportSessionDataModel>` or not, depending on the test (again, no way to know exactly how without seeing your logic):

   ```cs
   var response = new RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesResponse();
   ```
3. And override the `RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesAsync` method on the mock:

   ```cs
   var serviceClient = new Mock<IServiceClient>();
   serviceClient
       .Setup(x => x.RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesAsync(It.IsAny<RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesRequest>()))
       .Returns(response);
   ```
4. Now, if you've setup `response` in a way that triggers `GetSessionData` to return a `List<ExceptionReportSessionDataModel>` that has `Count > 0`, you can verify that log message, otherwise verify the opposite log message.

But IMO, the way you've written this code makes unit testing a chore. You don't seem to be taking advantage of dependency injection.

**UPDATE:**

It seems you can either assign `response` as:

```cs
var response = new RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesResponse
{
    RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesResult = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
}
```

and verify that `logger.LogInfo` is called with `Privilege.EditSession`, or assign response as:

```cs
var response = new RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesResponse
{
    RetrieveExceptionReportSessionDatesResult = string.Empty
}
```

and verify that `logger.LogWarn` is called with `Privilege.ViewOrderExceptionReport`.

Just one more observation - is there an off-by-one error in the for loop? (It is staring at index 1)

Comment: Well unfortunately I didn't write the endpoint, but I am calling this endpoint in an application we are building and I was asked to write some unit test on it. I am updating the question so you can see the GetSessionData method. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jaden Adams ok added a little more to the answer